# will Windows Server datacenter(or pro) 2019+ activate a server 2016 hyper-v vm

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, windows-activation

I have access to azure for education being that I both work for and attend a college that is enrolled in that program, so getting new versions of server are but a few clicks and some download time.

I have a computer running windows server 2016 datacenter, with 6 disks hosting a 20TB windows storage spaces array (with redundancy). Due to lack of checkpoints and some prior experience the bare-metal instance of windows server is running storage spaces and hyper-v and that's about it.

Active directory, DNS are in one VM(task scheduled to checkpoint monthly), and group policy, NPS and everything else are in a second vm also checkpointed monthly.

Newegg recently had a sale on some large datacenter HDD's so I put together a truenas box and made a full copy of my 20TB storage spaces array, as it is getting old and I had already replaced 2 of it's 6 disks but I was getting worried of a larger failure.

all 6 of the disks on the windows server are connect through a hub, and yesterday I discovered that hub has died (amazon put it's replacement on my porch a few hours ago, will install when I get home) I suspect the disks are ok for the time being but time will tell.

the VM's for AD and group policy grew too large to stay on the server boot disk and got migrated to the storage array and are presently non-functional.

Truenas can Host VM's and I was thinking of setting up server inside truenas's vm platform.
However my VMDK's that host active directory and the other one with group policy are running server 2016 and are activated by virtue of running on a server 2016 datacenter activated host computer (some microsoft secret sauce in hyper-v tells the VM's that the host is legit so the VM's get to be legit as well(the main difference between datacenter and pro, is datacenter allows an unlimited number of VM's pro allows 2(I can have unlimited but I am only using 2...))

***My Question is:*** If I put server 2019 or newer into the truenas VM platform and activate it; can I take my existing server 2016 AD and group Policies VMDK vm-disk files and import them and get them running in a activated manner, or will the fact that they would then be sub VM's inside a new and mis-matched version year of server cause them to become deactivated?

Comment: If you are asking if you can allow your Windows Server 2019 to become part of your 2016 domain, the answer to that question, of course it can.  You will be limited group polices that are available to Windows Server 2016.  Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2019 would require their own separate Windows license. Windows becoming not activated isn't a concern when dealing with legitimate license keys. There actually isn't any "secret sauce" built-into Hyper-V in reality you likely are lucky your current installation is activated.

Comment: No that wasn't what I was asking and there isn't any luck to the activation at all.

Right on the feature list web page for windows server pro it says you can have 2 virtual machines with server in it; on the data center feature list it says unlimited VM's

using a third party VM solution it does not work(or I could not make it work years ago when I tried); but as long as you use hyper-v and the bare metal server OS is activated then the VM's within it activate themselves because the host OS is activated and this is a stated feature of the product.

Comment: as for the question I was trying to ask: instead of bare metal server 2016 with 2 hyper-v sever 2016 instances

I want to:

have a server 2019 (vm in truenas but at the same tier in the flow chart as my bare metal 2016) and inside the truenas virtulized server 2019 I wanted to install hyper-v (vm's within a VM) and then import my existing VMDK disk files and spin them up in a their new home. However as their activate is tied to the OS that hyper-V is running on it begs the question: if the VM's are server 2016 but hyper-v is running on 2019 is the activation still valid

Comment: 2016 and 2019 require their own license. I don’t understand the question

Comment: I have access to azure for education software downloads I can get a server 2019 license at the press of a button, getting the license is not an issue. The question is if the VM’s running in hyper-v based on a prior server OS would auto activate as they for when all the versions align.

Comment: Right now Server 2016 bare metal (activated with a key code, provided by Microsoft); 2 Hyper-V Server 2016 VM’s (activated //NOT// with key code but by virtue of running on hyper-V ontop of properly activated host bare metal system (this is a feature of the pro & Datacenter version of server. Hyper-V tells the guest instances of server ‘host is legit, so you VM’s are also legit’)[The only feature difference I could find at all for any feature whatsoever is that Pro allows 2 VM’s activated in this way; Datacenter allows unlimited VM’s activated in this way)

Comment: The proposed question is if I install and activate with a key code server 2019 datacenter or newer and //IMPORT// my existing VM’s unchanged and thus still having inside themselves server 2016. Would the VM’s activate properly as they do now or would the fact they were a guest on a newer OS version cause the VM’s to no longer be valid unless I updated them to 2019 as well

Comment: That's really a question for Microsoft licensing.

Comment: No, AVMA only works with Datacenter Hyper-V.  Your 2016 Windows VMs will still be "licensed' but you'll need a key to activate them.  In your case, you'd assign the 2019 datacenter license to your physical server, licensing is purely paper based.  But, you'll need to use your 2016 and 2019 keys to activate the OS.  You may need to call MS since a DC key isn't designed to be used to activate VMs.  You may want to look into MAK/MS if you're planning on running multiple Windows Server VMs.